# What is the Tile ID for Ancient manipulator? (TModLoader)

Tags: c#

I'm making a mod in TModLoader, and I want to make the required crafting station the Ancient Manipulator. I've tried several different IDs, but none of them have worked. What is the Tile ID for the Ancient Manipulator?

Here's my code:

```
        {
            ModRecipe recipe = new ModRecipe(mod);
            recipe.AddIngredient(ItemID.FragmentVortex, 18); // What is in this recipe?
            recipe.AddTile(TileID.Anvils); // Which crafting station does this recipe need?
            recipe.SetResult(this);
            recipe.AddRecipe();
        }
```

Comment: Please add more context to your question as it's quite confusing, and a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

the name is
 LunarCraftingStation

Comment: To reviewers: be careful, this answer is very short, but answers exactly the question. Please do not recommend deletion.

Answer (score 0):

```
recipe.AddTile(412); //412 is the ID for the Ancient Manipulator Tile
```

You can find the ID's for certain Tiles here, if you ever need it.
https://github.com/tModLoader/tModLoader/wiki/Vanilla-Tile-IDs